# Microsoft Visual C++ repository

Tags: download, visual-c++, redistributable

I had a program looking for `MSVCR100.dll`, which after some looking realized it
is a part of *Microsoft Visual C++ 2010*. I found a download here:

http://microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=13523

However I was wondering: does Microsoft have a page with links to each version
of Visual C++, or some official way to browse the different versions? The page I
linked has no category tree, so I cannot use it to navigate "up", and if I do a
search:

http://microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadsDrillInResults.aspx?q=Visual+C%2b%2b+2010

it gives over 10 pages of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest versions of the redistributable packages for Visual C++
at [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](//support.microsoft.com/help/2977003). Here are
the versions available:

- Visual C++ 2019 (14.2)
- Visual C++ 2017 (14.1)
- Visual C++ 2015 (14.0)
- Visual C++ 2013 (12.0)
- Visual C++ 2012 (11.0)
- Visual C++ 2010 (10.0)
- Visual C++ 2008 (9.0)

Note that if the program you are trying to run is x86, the x64 redistributable
will not work.

Answer (score 1):

### Is there a page with links to the runtimes for Visual C++?

You can get the latest versions of the redistributable packages for Visual C++ at [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads):

> This article lists the download links for the latest versions of Microsoft Visual C++ [Visual C++ redistributable packages and Service Packs]

...

> More Information
>
> About Visual C++ Redistributable Packages
>
> Visual C++ Redistributable Packages install runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries on a computer that does not have Visual C++ installed. The libraries are required to run applications that are developed by using the corresponding version of Visual C++.

Comment: The OP noted, "which after some looking realized it is a part of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010".  I would suggest making a clear statement that a full Visual C++ 2010 is not needed (even though it surely does come with what is required).

Comment: @TOOGAM The link provided links to want the author requires to solve their problem.  There isn’t a way to partially install VC++.  Visual Studio and VC++ are two very different things

Comment: @TOOGAM Please read the page. It includes direct links to the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages as well as Service Packs. The links are not to a full version of the compiler.