# Windows 7 - 32bit version of mfc100u.dll in both 32 and 64 bit directories

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dll

I keep getting the same problem over and over again. After I install windows 7 some programs install Visual studio redistributable 2010 - both x86 and x64 versions. Everything runs fine for a while and then I get and error That a program can't run. Usually it's Nikon's ViewNX 2. When I check the program with depends it sais that MFC100U.DLL is x86 version. So I check it and indeed it's the same file in both locations:
C:\Windows\System32\mfc100u.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc100u.dll
Both files are x86 and are 4,422,992 bytes long. That's different from the one that's installed by the redistributable x86 - 4,368,720, so it must be comming from windows update.

I fix it by taking MFC100u.dll (the x64 versuib) from another computer and put it in C:\Windows\System32.

So why are Microsoft sending me the same bad file every time? Or is there anything else happening?

Edit: 
The question **is not a duplicate** of [Microsoft Visual C++ repository](https://superuser.com/questions/1257160/microsoft-visual-c-repository)
If you read carefully **I never said the file is missing**. I have both 64 bit and 32 bit versions of vc2010 installed, and everything works fine for a while until one day after some updates (but I'm not sure the updates are causing it) some programs stop working. I check them with dependancy walker and it says that the file MFC100u.dll in windows/system32 **is actually 32 bit**  while **it should be 64 bit**. So when this happens **both system32 and SysWOW64 have the same file** - same size, both 32 bit. And yes, I check that with a 64 bit program to make sure that windows/system32 is not redirected to the 32 bit version.

Note that this is the third time I reinstall my windows and this happens. and this is noticed on 3 computers in total. Something replaces the 64 bit version of this exact file with 32 bit version.

Comment: A file located in System32, on a 64-bit version of Windows, is not 32-bits it would be 64-bit bits.  "So why are Microsoft sending me the same bad file every time? " - There are multiple versions of the `Visual C++ redistributable 2010`, an application, can target specific version of the DLL.  You can have multiple versions of `Visual C++ redistributable 2010` installed.  They fixed that particular problem with `Visual C++ redistributable 2015+`.  If a program cannot run, it means, the correct version is not installed.

Comment: Like I said the file in system32 on my 64 bit OS WAS 32 bit - I checked it. That was actually the problem. After a while the 64 bit file is replaced with 32 bit and the programs that require it stop working.

Comment: I downloaded the application in question, within a virtual machine, and installed both 32-bit and 64-bit Visual C++ 2010.  Application run perfectly.  I was unable to reproduce this behavior

Comment: Well, I can't give you exact steps to reproduce. I haven't installed any of the VC dist. packages manually - only the ones that are bundled with other software. After I install windows, I update, then I install all my software and then later (last time was ~1 month) the problem happens. I say that it could be windows update problem because it's fine, then I update then on the other day it doesn't work, but I can't reproduce it on purpose. So it might not be windows update.However the dlls have now different size than when it they are first installed. Can I monitor what's writing these DLLs